# Cannot convert Bitmap to Drawable, why do i get this error?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, drawable

I have spend about 3 hours trying to figure this out and it seems so simple but i cant seem to work it out! Could someone please help me! All i want it to do it display an image from the drawable resources folder. It says that "cannot convert from Bitmap to Drawable".

```
package com.CS3040.Places;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import com.CS3040.*;
import com.CS3040.Coursework.R;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class PlaceOverlayItem extends OverlayItem {
    private final GeoPoint point;
    private final Place place;
    private final Drawable marker;
    //private final Context context;

    public PlaceOverlayItem(Context context, Place p, String type) {
        super(p.getGeoPoint(), p.getName(), p.getFormatted_address());

        if(type.equals("restaurant"))
        { 
            //this.marker =
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.restaurant);
            this.marker = bmp;

        } 

        //super.setMarker(this.marker);
        this.point = p.getGeoPoint();
        this.place = p;
    }

    /**
     * @return the point
     */
    public GeoPoint getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    /**
     * @return the place
     */
    public Place getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's right - [`Bitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) *doesn't* extend [`Drawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html). I haven't done any Android development, but it sounds like you want a [`BitmapDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html):

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.restaurant);
this.marker = new BitmapDrawable(resources, bmp);
```

Comment: I was just going to mention that i tried that and i get and error "The blank final field marker may not have been initialized" in the "public PlaceOverlayItem(Context context, Place p, String type) {
        super(p.getGeoPoint(), p.getName(), p.getFormatted_address());"

Comment: Thats a different error - after your `if` put an `else this.marker = null` so `marker` will always get some value

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your resource as a Drawable:

```
if(type.equals("restaurant"))
{ 
    this.marker = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.restaurant);
} else {
    // marker would get no value without that else case - not allowed if you declare it final
    this.marker = null;
}
```

Comment: i did this however i get a error on the public PlaceOverlayItem(Context context, Place p, String type) which says "The blank final field marker may not have been initialized". Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.restaurant);
this.marker = bmp;
```

to this:

```
Drawable d = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.restaurant);
d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
this.marker = d;
```

Comment: i did this however i get a error on the public PlaceOverlayItem(Context context, Place p, String type) which says "The blank final field marker may not have been initialized". Thanks for your help.